# How to build a probability distribution from locations with accuracies?

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

I have a set of $n$ GPS locations $l_i$ with latitude, longitude in degrees and accuracy in meters, corresponding to $3 σ$, i.e. the probability ≈ 0.997) $(lat_i, lng_i, acc_i)$ or $(lat_i, lng_i, σ_i = acc_i / 3)$.  They were gathered homogeneously in terms of space and time.  I want to use them to create a probability distribution in order to evaluate the likelihoods of the presence in polygons in a search perimeter.

For now I am using a Gaussian Mixture Model (`scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` in Python), passing to it the 2d-vectors $(lat_i, lng_i)$ and weights computed as follows (empirically): $p_i = 1 / acc_i$.  That gives me quite consistent results, however I wonder if GMM is the right tool here.  A single covariance matrix $∑$ is computed and the accuracies are essentially ignored, except from my quite random weights computation.

Wouldn't it be better to consider that every location $l_i$ follows a bivariate normal distribution $(μ_i, ∑_i)$ with probability density functions (PDF) $f_i$ and simply sum them with equal weights $p_i = 1 /n$: $f(x) = ∑p_if_i(x)$, effectively taken accuracies into account?
I consider computing $∑_i$ from $σ_i$, supposing that latitude and longitude are independent.  I have to "convert" meters into degrees, thus getting an ellipse.  $∑_i$ would then be a diagonal matrix.  Is that correct?
Am I right thinking that this second method would be mathematically more fair?

I also need to build a search perimeter for which the cumulative distribution function (CDF) is above some threshold $$ (for example $0.99$).  Since I am unable to compute the iso-density locus I use a convex hull of $N$ generated samples ($N$ being large enough).  Is there a better solution (like an exact solving), either in the GMM case or in the sum of bivariate normal distributions one?

Comment: Is gis.stackexchange.com a good place to ask this?